# Adaptar tamaño fuente a su contenedor C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un fomulario con varios controles, label, textBox, etc. Necesito redimensionar todos los controles cuando se redimensione el form y parece que lo he conseguido, pero aunque se redimensiones los controles, el tamaño de su fuente parece no cambiar, se queda igual de grande por lo que no se adapta, como puedo hacer para que el tamaño de mis label, textbox etc se adapten al tamaño del propio control?
Mi código es:

```
public partial class Marcador : Form
    {
        private Rectangle pictureBoxLocal;
        private Rectangle pictureBoxVisit;
        private Rectangle txtPuntosLocal;
        private Rectangle txtPuntosVisit;
        private Rectangle lblNomLocal;
        private Rectangle lblNomVisit;
        private Rectangle txtCrono;
        private Rectangle lblLetreroLocal;
        private Rectangle lblLetreroVisit;
        private Rectangle lblGuion;

        private Size formOriginalSize;

        public Marcador()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Marcador_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            formOriginalSize = this.Size;

            pictureBoxLocal = new Rectangle(mPictureBoxLocal.Location.X, mPictureBoxLocal.Location.Y, mPictureBoxLocal.Width, mPictureBoxLocal.Height);
            pictureBoxVisit = new Rectangle(mPictureBoxVisit.Location.X, mPictureBoxVisit.Location.Y, mPictureBoxVisit.Width, mPictureBoxVisit.Height);
            txtPuntosLocal = new Rectangle(mTxtPuntosLocal.Location.X, mTxtPuntosLocal.Location.Y, mTxtPuntosLocal.Width, mTxtPuntosLocal.Height);
            txtPuntosVisit = new Rectangle(mTxtPuntosVisit.Location.X, mTxtPuntosVisit.Location.Y, mTxtPuntosVisit.Width, mTxtPuntosVisit.Height);
            lblNomLocal = new Rectangle(mLblNomLocal.Location.X, mLblNomLocal.Location.Y, mLblNomLocal.Width, mLblNomLocal.Height);
            lblNomVisit = new Rectangle(mLblNomVisit.Location.X, mLblNomVisit.Location.Y, mLblNomVisit.Width, mLblNomVisit.Height);
            txtCrono = new Rectangle(mTxtCrono.Location.X, mTxtCrono.Location.Y, mTxtCrono.Width, mTxtCrono.Height);
            lblLetreroLocal = new Rectangle(mLblLetreroLocal.Location.X, mLblLetreroLocal.Location.Y, mLblLetreroLocal.Width, mLblLetreroLocal.Height);
            lblLetreroVisit = new Rectangle(mLblLetreroVisit.Location.X, mLblLetreroVisit.Location.Y, mLblLetreroVisit.Width, mLblLetreroVisit.Height);
            lblGuion = new Rectangle(mLblGuion.Location.X, mLblGuion.Location.Y, mLblGuion.Width, mLblGuion.Height);
        }

        private void resizeChildrenControls()
        {
            resizeControl(pictureBoxLocal, mPictureBoxLocal);
            resizeControl(pictureBoxVisit, mPictureBoxVisit);
            resizeControl(txtPuntosLocal, mTxtPuntosLocal);
            resizeControl(txtPuntosVisit, mTxtPuntosVisit);
            resizeControl(lblNomLocal, mLblNomLocal);
            resizeControl(lblNomVisit, mLblNomVisit);
            resizeControl(txtCrono, mTxtCrono);
            resizeControl(lblLetreroLocal, mLblLetreroLocal);
            resizeControl(lblLetreroVisit, mLblLetreroVisit);
            resizeControl(lblGuion, mLblGuion);
        }
        private void resizeControl(Rectangle originalControlRect, System.Windows.Forms.Control control)
        {
            float xRatio = (float)(this.Width) / (float)(formOriginalSize.Width);
            float yRatio = (float)(this.Height) / (float)(formOriginalSize.Height);

            int newX = (int)(originalControlRect.X * xRatio);
            int newY = (int)(originalControlRect.Y * yRatio);
            int newWidth = (int)(originalControlRect.Width * xRatio);
            int newHeight = (int)(originalControlRect.Height * yRatio);

            control.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
            control.Size = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
        }
 private void Marcador_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resizeChildrenControls();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final he podido solucionarlo por mi mismo, dejo el ejemplo por si le sirve a alguien.

Para que cambie la fuente es con:

```
control.Font = new Font(control.Font.FontFamily, newHeight/2);
```

Quedando el metodo de resizeControl asi:

```
private void resizeControl(Rectangle originalControlRect,    System.Windows.Forms.Control control)
        {
            float xRatio = (float)(this.Width) / (float)(formOriginalSize.Width);
            float yRatio = (float)(this.Height) / (float)(formOriginalSize.Height);

        int newX = (int)(originalControlRect.X * xRatio);
        int newY = (int)(originalControlRect.Y * yRatio);
        int newWidth = (int)(originalControlRect.Width * xRatio);
        int newHeight = (int)(originalControlRect.Height * yRatio);

        control.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
        control.Size = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
        try
        {
            control.Font = new Font(control.Font.FontFamily, newHeight/2);
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

El Try lo he metido porque podría encontrar controles que no tengan la propiedad FONT.

Gracias